# Will altering a primary key column from int to bigint rewrite the index before it finishes?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Doing a migration of a PostgreSQL column like this:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN id TYPE bigint;
```

Will this reindex the column while the `ALTER TABLE` lasts and holds its locks? Is it required to run `ANALYZE` after running the `ALTER`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement will rewrite the table and all its indexes, so it may take a long time, but afterwards everything will be there and ready, including indexes.

You should analyze the table, because statistics are not preserved.